# Turn off log4php logging programmatically

Tags: php, log4php

I am using log4php in my project.
But for deployment I want to turn off the logger using configuration array.

What is the parameter for turn logging OFF?

Comment: How about you don't issue commands like `$logger->info('...')` ?

Answer (score 2):

In the `config.xml`, set the `level`

```
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="myAppender" class="LoggerAppenderFile">
        <param name="file" value="myLog.log" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender_ref ref="myAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Or use the php config file `config.php`, do

```
return array(
    'rootLogger' => array(
        'level' => 'DEBUG',     // you need to change here to set the log level
        'appenders' => array('default'),
    ),
    'appenders' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'class' => 'LoggerAppenderFile',
            'layout' => array(
                'class' => 'LoggerLayoutSimple'
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'file' => '/var/log/my.log',
                'append' => true
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: OP wants to use configuration array instead of config XML.

Comment: set `level` to `off` , better approach.